One Task is long running in executor and pods are stuck
We're encountering a recurring issue where a pod becomes stuck after running for some time (usually 1 or 2 days), consistently halting during the fileScanRdd process while reading Parquet files. This same occurrence has happened multiple times, persisting even after restarts.
Our workflow involves

Reading from Kafka Topic and write into local filesystem as Parquet file in another spark process
Reading Parquet files from the local filesystem and then writing them to a database. - Pod stuck

Upon analysis, we've observed the following:

Out of 23 tasks, 22 tasks are completed successfully, but one task remains stuck and uncompleted for over 4 hours.
Executor 1 has completed 10 tasks, while Executor 2 has completed 12 tasks. The long-running task resides within Executor 2.

After deleting the one executor, it is started processing.
There are no apparent network issues affecting the process.
Here are the relevant configurations:

Spark Version: 3.3.2

maxBytesPerTrigger: 10,000,000 (Approximately 200 files per trigger)

Executors: 2

Cores per Executor: 10

Parallelism/Partitions: 20

12gb memory

4gb heap memory in jvm

File system - _delta_log files having 500+ files and each json file having 3kb filesize and checkpoint.paraquet having 70mb


df.writeStream().format("classA").options(props).start();
In ClassA 
  df.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY());
  Accumulator in map
  collect the dataset - **Filescanrdd is happening and stuck intermittently**

We're seeking assistance in resolving this persistent issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
Spark UI:
Long running Taskid - 991849 but in running query it is showing the taskid - 991812, 991813 which is showing is finished in task list.
which task is causing issue here ?
_delta folder size - 50gb
Files count in _delta - 4075









After Killing the stuck task, Same thread is in running status and one more thread added in running status and stuck .


Sounds like you have a skew in your data.

but Spark 3 version should handle the adaptive skew rite ?  or adding below properties can solve the problem
spark.sql.adaptive.enabled true
spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled true
but i don't see high records in this single tasks.

AQE can come into effect only after statistics have been collected at a stage boundary. Not sure how big your data is - I'd use repartiton to help establish if skew is indeed the problem. As far as AQE goes, you can try adjusting the parameters "spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.skewedPartitionThresholdInBytes" and  "spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.skewedPartitionFactor" to make sure AQE kicks in.

Added additional details from Spark-UI. Can you check and provide your inputs.

@xuxu - After repartition also, we are getting same issue.
